# Why would you use the stack if there is a possibility of stack overflow

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class that repsents my application: (sorry for not showing both h and cpp but this is for brevity)

```
class App
{
    App()
    {
        window( new Window() );
        window->Height( 400 );
        window->Width( 400 );
        window->Title( "Bob" );
    }

    unique_ptr<Window> window;
    // ... Possibly more variables
}

class Window
{
public:

    // Get
    int Height(){ ... };
    int Width(){ ... };
    string Title(){ ... };    

    // Set
    void Height( int height ){ ... };
    void Width( int width ){ ... };
    void Title( string title ){ ... };

private:

    int height;
    int width;
    string title;

    // ... Possibly more variables

}
```

---

```
App app;

int main()
{

}
```

All of the `int` and `string` types inside my `Window` class are declared on the stack. At some point, I'm going to end up with a stack overflow if I keep declaring stuff on the stack inside these classes... right?

**So my question is**... Why would you ever want to declare stuff on the stack? shouldn't we I just be doing this instead?

```
// ...
App()
{
    window( new Window() );
    window->Height( unique_ptr<int>( new int( 400 ) ) );
    window->Width( unique_ptr<int>( new int( 400 ) ));
    window->Title( unique_ptr<string>( new string( "Bob" ) ) );
}
// ...
private:

    unique_ptr<int> height;
    unique_ptr<int> width;
    unique_ptr<string> title;

...
```

The difference being that the memory for the integers and strings are now declared on the heap.

Comment: On many platforms, your `unique_ptr<int>` would require **more** stack space than an `int`.  You also don't know whether `Window` is on the stack to begin with.

Comment: I think you don't understand the distinction between the string itself, which may wind up on the stack, and the *contents* of the string, which don't. The string is a fixed size, you can find out what it is with `sizeof(string)`. But clearly the *contents* of a string can vary in size.

Comment: `All of the int and string types inside my Window class are declared on the stack.` This statement doesn't make any sense. Types don't occupy space (on the stack or otherwise) - objects do. In any case, in the code you show there's barely any object on the stack.

Comment: The stack can be arbitrary sized. You can set the stack to be very large if you want. It's not different from any other place in the memory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about as likely as heap overflow if you don't do something stupid like infinite recursion. Your objects are on the order of a dozen or two bytes in size. The stack on a reasonable machine is probably going to be on the order of a million bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when you declare window as `unique_ptr<Window> window` you are declaring something on the stack. In this case an instance of `unique_ptr<Window>`. It is fine to declare ints and other small primitives or structs on the stack because even if you declare them on the heap you will need to declare the pointer to them on the stack. You will always need to hold a pointer to the location on the heap, in the stack so if your data type is smaller than a pointer (or close to the same size) than it is even more efficient to hold it on the stack rather than the heap. This is because it is quicker to access the stack than the heap, and memory wise you have to store two objects when storing on the heap (the pointer and the object itself) and only one when storing on the stack.

Take `std::string` for instance. It probably holds internally a pointer to a location on the heap where the raw data is stored. So on the stack you are holding a pointer and on the heap the raw data (string literals are a bit different put the general idea remains).

In general there is little point in storing an int in a `unique_ptr` unless it is the address of an array. It is more efficient and easier to maintain if you just declare it as a raw int.

Comment: Daymmmm, that makes ALOT of sense brother... THANK YOU... I am now officially enlightnededededd ddd d? d or however you spell it!

Comment: Those are class members. They will only be on the stack when a class instance is itself on the stack - which is not the case in the code shown. The only instance of `Window` is very deliberately allocated on the heap.

Comment: The OP declare App on the stack. Well in global storage. But my point remains.

Comment: I guess they mean that even though i declared App on the stack, Window where i declared a new pointer was on the heap... ergo the confusion there right?

Comment: @BenjyKessler and that `App` on the stack has a **pointer** to a `new Window()`.

Comment: @BenjyKessler No, `app` is not on the stack. More precisely, `app` is not an object with automatic storage duration.

Comment: Ahh, you're right I missed the Window class entirely.

Comment: But my point about declaring small data types on the stack remains.

Comment: I've edited my question very slightly including the declarations of the integers and strings... i just wanted to make sure we were all on the same wavelength... does this answer still make sense now?

Comment: You updated your answer to say unless it is the address of an array. So i guess it might be worth declaring strings on the heap as they could be huge right?

Comment: So yes and no. Declaring a large array of chars on the stack is silly. But when using std::string it implicitly allocates memory on the heap for large strings. You don't need to allocate a pointer to std::string.

Comment: Argh, i know i keep asking pretty much the same question but... in the case of Window...that's a good choice to declare that on the heap as it could possibly require a lot of space right?.. so apart from primitives it's a good idea (generally) to declare on the heap. (is that a yes and no again)

Comment: It's also fine to declare Window on the stack. It might be a little better to declare it on the heap if you are going to copy it around a lot. It is also better to allocate on the heap for code clarity because App doesn't need to include Window. You can just forward declare it. That is why it generally preferred to use pointers. I don't think you will see much of a performance difference though.

Comment: Be aware that there can be significant performance differences in a multithreaded application.  Heap allocation/deallocation tends to be single-threaded and can become a bottleneck for multithreaded applications.

Comment: So I can never assign a processor to do a specific set of allocation and another to do another set? It all happens on one thread? That doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 5):

`Why would you ever want to declare stuff on the stack?`

2 reasons I can think of:

1. Performance: The stack is extremely fast. I remember hearing this somewhere but the best way to improve performance is to avoid a trip to the heap.
2. Complexity: Using dynamic memory creates more complexity as you have to think about memory management. Using the stack keeps it much more simple than using the heap. Using dynamic memory increases the complexity of your program.

Comment: Also, function parameters must needs live on the stack; there's no choice to put them elsewhere.

Comment: The stack isn't faster than the heap nor vice-versa; memory is memory. Stack _allocations_ tend to be faster than heap _allocations_.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik function parameters can live anywhere, and often live in registers or nowhere at all. It depends heavily on the ABI and optimisations.

Comment: @rightfold I really meant "on the stack" as a shorthand for "have automatic storage duration". I was inexcusably sloppy in my wording, I suppose.

Comment: @rightfold: `tend to be faster`? Do you have an example of where heap allocation is faster? I would be intrigued ;).

Comment: @JesseGood arena-based allocators and compacting garbage collectors can be as fast or faster.

Comment: @rightfold: Maybe in theory? Ive never seen anything to back this up. Do you have a benchmark?

Comment: @rightfold: The stack isn't fragmented and is used frequently. It is nearly guaranteed to be in L1 cache... and thus faster.

Answer (score 0):

You are prematurely worrying about optimizing stack usage.

You indicated C++.

For C++ on Linux, the default stack size for ubuntu 12.04 and 15.04 is 8 MegaBytes.

The sizeof() Height and Width are 4 bytes each.

If you are using std::string, and gcc 4.9 on Ubuntu 15.04, the 
    sizeof(an_empty_std_string_object) is 8 bytes (on the stack)

Additionally
    the sizeof(a_100_char_string_object) is only 8 bytes.
    I would guess that std::string is a simple wrapper around dynamic memory, but I have never checked.

So an 8 MByte stack will hold more than 10^6 of your 16 byte objects.  Maybe you could fill this stack using recursion.

---

Imagine you move all 16 bytes of your object to the heap (i.e. you new your object to the heap)

You would still use 8 bytes (on 64 byte linux) on the stack to point to your object.

I have not looked at how big a smart pointer is, but it will probably be 16 bytes, not sure yet.

---

Perhaps you are worried enough to put each of your objects into a vector.  An empty vector is 24 bytes, and so is a 1000 element vector, and so is a 1 Million Element vector, ...

Anyway, if you are nearing stack limits (it is doable, I've done it with recursive algorithms), in Linux you can change the stack size ... I have tried a 1 GByte stack ... just to see how far that recursive program would get.  Not that much further.  (Sorry, I did not finish that experiment.)

---

> All of the int and string types inside my Window class are declared on
>   the stack.

No, not really.  Your int and string types are declared as data attributes of your class instances.  If your class instances are instantiated on the heap (i.e. using new), then that data will be in the heap, not on the stack.